# How to not allow the 'bounce' effect on the end of scrolling on a website?

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to get this scrolling effect i have seen on the website http://www.unheap.com , if you scroll to the bottom or to the right you'll notice that you can't scroll past whatsoever. Most website including this one allow you to scroll past slightly with a lot of resistance but I'm trying to replicate the example above where you can't scroll past at all. Anyone know of any plugins or methods on how to go about creating this effect?

Comment: What do you mean 'scroll past'? Scroll past what? What about users of OS X, which supports bounce scrolling?

Comment: Sorry can you please explain? In that example you can't scroll bottom past the page because the there's no more content inside that page...

Comment: @BenM Thats exactly his point, it doesn't do the bounce scrolling on OS X. How did they get around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual website itself is 100% the width and height of the page and any scrolling that occurs is accomplished via an absolutely positioned container with `overflow: scroll`.

**EDIT**

The actual `overflow` is set on the `.grid` element, which is inside the absolutely positioned `.container` element.

**EDIT #2**

The author is also using `jScrollPane`, but you can prevent the bouncing effect simply by making your body 100% width and height and absolutely positioning a container that has overflow set to scroll.

**EDIT #3**
See the attached code snippet - (you may have to copy and paste it into it's own HTML file because of the way SO displays snippets). There is no bouncing.

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html,
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden;}
body>div { height: 50vh; overflow: auto; padding: 10px; background: #000; position: absolute; width: 100px; top: 100px; left: 100px;}
body>div>div { height: 1000px; background: #0f0;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>scrollable content</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry but i see 
`element.style {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 920px;
}
.grid {
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}`
Not exactly what you said.

Comment: Turning off the height and overflow properties of the container does not make the site bounce like any other site on OS X. I'm thinking this is more likely to be javascript.

Comment: Your edit seems to make sense, but again, turning off all these properties and cranking up the height of many others does not seem to reinstate the default scrolling of OS X.

Comment: Ahhhhh, that makes sense. So the actual scrolling is the content being able to scroll which i presume doesn't have the bounce effect (learned from above^). But still just because the rest is 100% why does that stop the bounce effect? If i went and made the html of a site width: 100% and height:100% with nothing else i would still be able to see the bounce effect per se. Sorry for being confused, thanks for your help though!

Comment: @OllieKlein - add `*{ margin:0; padding:0; }` and you will not see a bounce effect.

Comment: @Adam you also need to set your `body`s `overflow` to `hidden` if you want to do it CSS only, otherwise it does not work as suggested (also, testing this does not work inside iFrames so a JSFiddle is out... But I just tested it locally and the scorlling only ends after setting the body as well)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your help! Massively appreciated! Works perfectly :)